# pygame cant play mp3 after grabbing a screenshot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have some code for PyGame to play an mp3. but I can't play the mp3 after grabbing a screenshot

file_A.py

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
def play(PATH, target):

    # play the sound
    print("play", target + ".mp3")
    mixer.music.load(PATH + target + ".mp3")
    mixer.music.play()

play("x","y")                   // its work if i call here
```

file_B.py

```
from .file_A import play
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

def main():

    play("x1","y")                           // its working here, but
    left = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1,2,3,4))    // after grab
    play("x2","y")                           // log printed that method called but sound not working
```

`python 3.7.4`
`pygame 1.9.6`
`pyscreenshot 1.0.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the main problem, its not a bug. but the audio interupted coz all code in that method already executed and the method done before mixer play di audio

file_B.py

```
from .file_A import play
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
import time

def main():

    play("x1","y")                           // its working here, but
    left = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1,2,3,4))    // after grab
    play("x2","y")                           // log printed that method called but sound not working
    time.sleep(n)                            // wait the audio play
```

or

add this on file_a.py after mixer.play

```
while mixer.music.get_busy(): 
        time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the files are in the same directory, my only assumption could be that when the function is imported into another file it may encounter path issues and hence it may not play the file.

I am also a bit baffled that your path is called `"xy.mp3"`. 
You may try giving it an absolute path, e.g.

Change your function definition to the following and try calling it from `file_B.py`

```
def play():

    # play the sound
    print("play", target + ".mp3")
    mixer.music.load("c:/programs/mygame/music/8bit-jingle-twist.mp3")
    mixer.music.play()
```

Also, consider adding this line `pygame.mixer.music.stop()` to the play function to make sure that music channel in use is properly termianted before a next instance play instance is acquired.

Comment: i thinks the problem not from pygame, coz everything work properly if the mixer play before grab screen shot using pyscreenshot.

just focus to file_B.py comment

Comment: What happens if you comment out this `left = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(1,2,3,4))  ` and run it? Does the sound work?

Comment: code edited for play x1 and x2. while grab exist, x1 work, and x2 not working. but if the i comment the grab. both not working

Comment: i found the problem if i put time.sleep(x) in the end of method, its work. so the problem is the audio interrupted/destroyed coz all code on that method already executed adn the method.

Comment: i already post the solution on comment, but i cant mark that to the answer today. so thanks for help me debug this problem.